# Mutex using 2 variables

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, architecture, mutex, semaphore

I am working on a system that consists of 2 Independent devices that exchange data through a "common memory".

To sync them, I wanted to use a memory location as a "state variable" or a mutex. Where the first device would take the mutex and the second would wait for it to be released and vice-versa. But now I have discovered that one of those devices can either read OR write from the same location. It cannot do both.

So now I am trying to think of a way to implement a mutex using 2 variables. One where the first device will write and second would read, and the other where the first would read and second would write.

Is this an unsafe approach? Because I think this would create a lot of read/write cycles and possibly race conditions. I've always seen mutexes being implemented with only one variable, so any guidance on this would be very very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inventing the collision detection algorithim in [CSMA](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collision-detection-csmacd/), probably not what you want to do, but may be your only choice to be successful.  Is there a reason you aren't creating a memory location for each device to write to, and have the other device read from that location?  More of a pub-sub than a truly shared memory model.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks for that. I _am_ using a kind of pub-sub model. One memory area is designated for one device and another memory area for the other device. My only concern is that these devices don't start reading while the other is in the middle of writing. And to make sure that the data in 2 different memories correspond the the same instance.